# Is there Chinese slang for sexual references?

Tags: simplified-characters

Trying to figure out how to write Daddy in the sexual sense. Not the father-to-child kind like 爸爸.

In America, certain slang is used during sex like "daddy", "papi", etc. To refer to the guy by the girl. In turn, the guy would call her his "little girl", "princess", "little slut", etc.

Is there a chinese version of that or do I have literally write like "sex daddy" or "fuck daddy" like 性 爸爸 or  迪克 爸爸 or 性父亲?

And which one is more fitting for this situation?

Comment: watch some Chinese X rated movies and you will learn what are being said during sex.

Comment: So I take it that you dont know yourself then. Okay, I gotcha. I don't want to know what is being said during sex in chinese, I just want that term specifically.

Comment: The term you want probably is "干爹"(literally a step dad), which is used by some people for this purpose. In turn, the girl is called "干女儿".

Comment: Thank you, I've been asking my friends that know chinese but they dont know either other than 爸爸. So I guess 干爹 is more accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term sugar daddy has been translated as such:

- [甜爹](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%94%9C%E7%88%B9) is an option, but it looks like a direct translation from English and doesn't seem to be very widespread, as a term.
- [干爹](https://www.backchina.com/forum/20160424/info-1373160-1-1.html) is another option and it seems to be the most common.
- [糖爸爸](https://www.backchina.com/forum/20160424/info-1373160-1-1.html) is another.
- [甘爹](https://www.zhihu.com/question/39746455) is also an option.
- 金主爸爸

---

If you're looking for just *daddy* you can see that both 爹 and 爸 are used in the above terms, but it would be quite ambiguous by itself.